# Error occured when trying to run android device monitor in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

when i am trying to run android device monitor in android studio a dialog box is appearing and showing the error as :

```
an error has occured.See the log file
C:\Users\.android\monitor-workspace\.metadata\.log
```

getting the same error when trying to run from C:\Users\Android\sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86 as an administrator.

can anybody help me in solving this error?

this is log file error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.<init>(ModelServiceImpl.java:96)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:446)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:182)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:557)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorApplication.start(MonitorApplication.java:86)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: Have you opened .log to see what the error is?

Comment: there is no error in logcat

Comment: So if there is no error, how do we help you _solve_ the _inexistent_ error? There is an error, we need to see what the error is.

Comment: i am just clicking on android device monitor icon and a dialog box of monitor is showing with the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Try running monitor.exe in /monitor-x86_64/ folder as Administrator

Comment: getting the same error and  also tried running android studio as an administrator but still getting the same error.